# How to create a countdown till a specific day Android

Tags: android, countdown

I want to make a countdown until a certain day but I don't know how to do it.

I want the countdown to count days, hours, minutes and seconds.

The final day will be set into the countdown with the format **DAY/MONTH/YEAR**. Ex: 11/9/15

Thank you and sorry for my English :P

**EDIT:**

What I want is the next:

You have a string that's a date (20/9/15). I want to make a countdown that counts **DAYS, HOURS, MINUTES & SECONDS** from today till the date. The countdown should be displayed on a textView

Thanks :D

Comment: It is hard to catch what do you want, and what did you tried...

Comment: There is literallyc a `CountdownTimer` class in Android. Please read the docs

Comment: Store target datetime. Have timer that ticks every second. On tick display difference between current datetime and target datetime. Come back with your attempts when you get stuck with a more specific problem

Comment: @musefan I'm new to Java and I don't know how to do it. I you can help me I'll be so happy :D

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Java (you don't say), use the getTime method of the java.util.Date objects indicating now and then, get the difference between them to figure out the number of days, hours, minutes, etc... remaining.

```
public String timeRemaining(Date then) {
  Date now = new Date();
  long diff = then.getTime() - now.getTime();
  String remaining = "";
  if (diff >= 86400000) {
    long days = diff / 86400000
    remining += "" + days + (days > 1) ? "days" : "day";
    diff -= days * 86400000;
  }
  //... similar math for hours, minutes
  return remaining;
}
```